# Cloning div instances in jquery when scrolling

Tags: jquery

Using sql and php, i return uniques divs.

I want to be able to clone (as shown my in [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FH5SYCB1S0P4)), those single id divs when scrolling down and making them disappear when reaching the next div. For the moment im using fixed ypositions to affect the creation and deletion of div.

I would like to get each div position and clone them when scrolling into their area.

As you can see in my example, i'm currently affecting the first div. I would like to be able use my function on each div.

Is there a way to run the function in a "range"? Let's say the first div is a 0, the second a 500 and the third at 1000. if the yposition is 200, could it run the function for the interval 0-500. If it is a 700, run for the interval 500-1000.

Here is the jquery code that can be executed on my example link:

```js
var count = 0;
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
        var scroll_pos_test = 0;
        var scroll_pos_max = 200;
        var direction = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (direction > lastScrollTop && y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && y_scroll_pos < scroll_pos_max) {
            function cook() {
                if (count > 1) {
                    $(".half").first().clone().not(".dup").addClass("dup").appendTo('#box1');
                    count = 0;
                }
            };

            setTimeout(cook, 50);
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        } else {
            $(".dup").remove();
        }

        lastScrollTop = direction;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use ScrollMagic for your solution:
http://scrollmagic.io/

In a nutshell: you can set a trigger at a specific point, in your case, the top of the page and do fancy stuff with html-elements when they hit or pass this trigger.

Example: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html

More demos: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html

Documentation: http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html